# How to block all .xyz referral spam using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, google-analytics, referrer-spam

There is a large list of `.xyz` referral spam domains in my GA.
I can name them all separately in my `.htaccess`, but I want to block them all forever.
How can I block them all using 1 line in my `.htaccess`?